# Asp.net MVC when to reload claims when lost

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, claims-based-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I have added a few custom claims when logging in.

```
private async Task SignInAsync(ApplicationUser user, bool isPersistent)
{
    AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
    var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        var accesses = _roleAccessRepository.GetAssignedAccess(roleId);
        foreach (var access in accesses)
        {
           identity.AddClaim(new Claim("AccessCode", access));
        }
    AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);
}
```

They work fine until I recently found that after certain inactivity, I assume of more than 30 minutes, these claims are lost. However the user is still logged in.

How do I reload these claims when the user is still logged in?

**Update: How it occured.**

I logged in to a user and then after roughly 30 minutes opened it again, and logged out of it. Instead of being logged out it refreshed my page, with no claims.

Comment: Are you using a state server to handle session state?

Comment: I have not handled any session state.

Comment: Ok.  It might be worth looking at enabling the Asp.net Session State service on your server and configuring your application to use it.  Without using the session state server or a database to store the session state, it might not persist beyond when your application is recycled periodically after inactivity.   I'm a bit confused as to why you'd lose the claims and not the login though :/, I would have thought it's all or nothing

Comment: Ok thanks for the info. I don't know how it happened. I will update on description.

Comment: @Coulton This is Asp.Net Identity tricks and nothing to do with a session, as session is not used here at all.

Comment: It stores the login state in a cookie?

Comment: @Coulton yes, cookie only.

Comment: The code posted will definitely store a cookie and set session values.   `AuthenticationManager.SignIn` certainly will...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are facing `SecurityStampValidator` in action. In the standard MVC5 template from VS2013/VS2015 there is a file `App_Start\Startup.Auth.cs` that has these lines:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
        // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
        // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
        OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
            validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
            regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
    }
});
```

You need to look at `SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity` - this method regenerates cookie every 30 minutes (in default configuration). And it does not preserve claims added outside of `user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager)`.

So you need to find `ApplicationUser` class and modify `GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)` method to include your claims. And don't add claims anywhere else.

Comment: Spot on, thanks. Anyway a short problem with this on my side, is i have `ApplicationUser` on a separate class project, which is used by all my other projects, so adding to it will cause cyclic reference error. Can i use or how to use spearate `GenerateUserIdentityAsync` on `regenerateIdentity`?

Comment: Yes, you can create a new method for creating Identity and pass that as a function parameter for `SecurityStampValidator`. You can have a few of them for every project you are using.

Comment: I used a new `CreateIdentityAsync` from `manager`. The the user which i already logged in(i have not signed out since the loss of claims), their claims are not being reloaded.

Comment: Try cleaning the cookies and logging-in again. And for testing purposes you can reduce `validateInterval` to a few seconds.